# How to use the output of aggregation as the input in other in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t80R.jpg)I have to find the data of last 10 days and then aggregate the result by grouping on one column.

below is my code:

```
 function countHits(){
    client.search({
      //size:0,
      body:{
        "aggs":{
                "distinct_value":{
                        "date_range":
                            {
                                    "field":"@timestamp",
                                    "format":"dd-MM-yyyy",
                                    "ranges":
                                        [
                                              {"to":"now/d"},
                                              {"from":"now-10d/d"}
                                        ]
                            }
                    }

            },"aggs":{
                "distinct_value" :{
                   "date_histogram":{
                       "field" :"@timestamp",
                       "interval":"day"
                    }
                }
            }

      }
  }).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
      }
    )
```

the first aggregation gives two buckets  "key:"*-11-07-2016"" and key:"01-07-2016-*"and their doc_counts and then second aggregation aggregates on the whole result .
but i want to put the second aggregation on the result getting from only key key:"01-07-2016-*"

can someone help me on this.

Comment: i removed to parameter and now getting the proper result only -one bucket only which gives result from last 10 days .

Comment: Place the second aggregation over the `date_range`(inside `distinct_value`).

Comment: that will not result in the desired result - i want group by day aggregation for last 10 days .

Comment: You could have a range filter for your dates, and over than aggregation, do a `date_histogram`, then a `terms` aggregation with the column you want to show that has the data. Also you could do add a script to show various columns separated by a `|` symbol or something like that.

Comment: i am getting day wise splitted buckets but i should get 10 buckets from 01-07-2016 to 11-07-2016 but i am getting from 16-06-2016 . dont know what i am missing .

Comment: Did you filtered your aggregation by date before the other aggregations? Remember to add the other aggregations inside the main aggregation.

Comment: now i have added the filter:but same result.

Comment: "aggs":
     {
       "filter":{
          "date_range":
          {
            "field":"@timestamp",
            "format":"dd-MM-yyyy",
            "ranges":
            [
                    {"from":"now-9d/d"}
               ]
          }
         }
     },
     "aggs":{
       "distinct_count":
       {
        "date_histogram":{
              "field" :"@timestamp",
              "interval":"day"
           }
       }
     }

Comment: place the second aggregation right after the `}` of `filter` so that your `date_histogram` works over the filtered result. You have 2 separated aggregations instead of nested ones.